# Android ListView Onclick Intent data delay (work in second time click)

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-activity, android-volley

I would like show a item details when I click a item in ListView, those details was got from database via Volley. I finished the code but the problem is:
It only work in second time click. 
For example when I click **item1**(data->Intent), jump to details Activity, but it **only show the default layout** (every element in view is null). Then click back to previous ListView and click **item1**, **everything display**.
Now, if I click **item2**, it will show **item1** in details page. Back to ListView click **item2**, will show item2.

Here is my code:
**ListView:**

```
       lvResults.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            /**
             * get data from db based on id_product
             */
          Bean bean = resultAdapter.getItem(position);//GET ITEM POSITION
          getPromotionById(bean.getIdProduct());//GET DATA JSONOBJECT FROM DATABASE via Volley

          Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
          intent.putExtra("item", itemToPass);
          startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

**getPromotionById(String id_product)**

```
    private void getPromotionById(String id_product) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("id_product",id_product);

    CustomRequest jsonObjectRequest = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, showUrl,map,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONObject promotion = response.getJSONObject("product");
                itemToPass.setIdProduct(promotion.getString("id_product"));
                itemToPass.setTitle(promotion.getString("name"));
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {}});
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

**DetailActivity:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    item = new Item();
    item = (Item) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("item");

    setContentView(R.layout.item_detail_1);

    itemTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    setData(item);
}
private void setData(Item item) {
    new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img))
            .execute("url");
    itemTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
}
```

[1st click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ayqjs.png)

[2nd click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/445Nn.png)

Comment: use ViewHolder pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting data from database via Volley so it need some time to get successful.
Therefore, if the data is not get successful yet, and you pass it to next `Activity`, you will get null value in next `Activity`

**Solution**
You need to wait until the data is get successful
After that, you pass it to next `Activity` via Intent

```
CustomRequest jsonObjectRequest = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, showUrl,map,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONObject promotion = response.getJSONObject("product");
                itemToPass.setIdProduct(promotion.getString("id_product"));
                itemToPass.setTitle(promotion.getString("name"));

                // Move Intent to here
                Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("item", itemToPass);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            ...
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**For your case:**
As I see, you read your data in database and waiting response call back. But if you haven't receive call back yet, you app call go to another activity then that is the reason why you don't see anything.

You can update like this :

```
 private void getPromotionById(String id_product) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("id_product",id_product);

    CustomRequest jsonObjectRequest = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, showUrl,map,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONObject promotion = response.getJSONObject("product");
                itemToPass.setIdProduct(promotion.getString("id_product"));
                itemToPass.setTitle(promotion.getString("name"));

                //after receive call back, you can start your activity instead of start right after call function read database
                Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("item", itemToPass);
                startActivity(intent);
                }catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {}
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```